# How to catch specific hibernate exception in java

Tags: java, json, hibernate, exception

I want to catch specific field name in catch block if any hibernate exception occurs. For example : I've column called "product_desc", if i try to insert more than 1000 character it should throw - Data too long for product_desc - this message i've to catch in "Catch Clause".

My input format is Json request like below:

```
{
"product": [
    {
        "prod_name": "Apple iphone",
        "price": "500",
        "prod_desc": "Test description."
    }
]
```

}

if user try to insert more than specified length, then "prod_desc" will fail and  - hibernate throws an exception but I want to catch the column name in catch block and show to end user stating that prod_desc value is too long to insert.

It would be really appreciated and helpful, if someone could help me to handle this scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may get hibernate exception like 
org.hibernate.exception.DataException

Catch such exception and get the exception message,In this case you will get message as

```
MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'prod_desc' at row 1
```

From the message,you will get column name.

Write you own RuntimeException with message as you wish.